# How to remove or hide ?lang= from url if select other languages

Tags: php

I have a language selector script. The codes looks like these:

index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$allowed_lang = array('en','de');

if (isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed_lang) === true) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
} else if (isset($_SESSION['lang']) === false) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}

include ''. $_SESSION['lang'] .'.php';

echo $lang['hello'] , '!';

?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?lang=en">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="?lang=de">Deutsch</a></li>
</ul>
```

en.php

```
<?php

$lang = array(
    'hello' => 'Hello',
);

?>
```

de.php

```
<?php

$lang = array(
    'hello' => 'Hallo',
);

?>
```

The default language is english of course, and if I select another language (e.g German), then after the language change the url is `index.php?lang=de`. After switching to English the url is `index.php?lang=en`.

How can I remove or hide `?lang=en` or `?lang=de` from the url, so if I click the "deutsch" link, tthe language will switch but not append anything to the current URL (e.g `index.php`)?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: The usual approach is to send the chosen language once, visible, as a HTTP GET parameter (as you currently do) and store the chosen value in the server side session. Then you redirect the client to the URL _without_ the parameter which is now available in the server side session _without_ having to be appended to any further request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GET` parameters for the language selection, you could use `POST` parameters. So you'd have to make the language selector a `form` which calls the document itself (i.e. *without* an `action` attribute, but with `method="post"`) and send and receive the language selection as a `POST` variable, i.e. not visible.

After that (i.e. for the following pages the user switches to) you could use session variables, cookies or local storage to save and call the selected language.